# Server Cannot Decrypt Connection Strings in Config File

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encryption

I have a .NET 4.7.1 console application that has some encrypted connection strings stored in the app.config file. This app runs fine when debugging in visual studio on my *local machine*, however when I run a build of the application on our *server*, I get the following error: **Failed to decrypt using provider 'customProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened.**

Some things to note:

There are other apps that run on the server (web apps running through IIS) that were encrypted the same way, and have no issues decrypting their connection strings.

I encrypted the connection strings in the app config using the following command: aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" . -prov "customProvider"

To do this, I had to change the app.config file to be named web.config, and then changed it back after running the command.